# unable to convert the buffer type array to image in javascript

Tags: javascript, base64, buffer

[From server i got that response shown in pic, how to convert the buffer array data to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm8BK.png)

let image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data;

Comment: is `data` a base64 string? no, then that won't work - you need to convert that data you have to a base64 string

Answer (score 1):

Your `data:` URI prefix says the data will be Base64-encoded (which is normal for `data:` URIs), but your data clearly isn't Base64-encoded.

You need to Base64 encode the data prior to appending it to the URL. [This question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript) tell you how to do that.

If we assume you implement one of the approaches from those answers and call the function `base64encode`, then:

```
let imageURI = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64encode(data);
```

Of course, I'm assuming `data` encodes a JPEG image.

For instance, if you wanted to use the `btoa` approach:

```
function base64encode(data) {
    return btoa(data.map(v => String.fromCharCode(v)).join(""));
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function base64encode(data) {
    return btoa(data.map(v => String.fromCharCode(v)).join(""));
}

const data = [
    0xff, 0xd8, 0xff, 0xe0, 0x00, 0x10, 0x4a, 0x46, 0x49, 0x46, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x48,
    0x00, 0x48, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xdb, 0x00, 0x43, 0x00, 0x03, 0x02, 0x02, 0x03, 0x02, 0x02, 0x03,
    0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x04, 0x03, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x08, 0x05, 0x05, 0x04, 0x04, 0x05, 0x0a, 0x07,
    0x07, 0x06, 0x08, 0x0c, 0x0a, 0x0c, 0x0c, 0x0b, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x12, 0x10, 0x0d,
    0x0e, 0x11, 0x0e, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x10, 0x16, 0x10, 0x11, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x15, 0x15, 0x0c, 0x0f,
    0x17, 0x18, 0x16, 0x14, 0x18, 0x12, 0x14, 0x15, 0x14, 0xff, 0xdb, 0x00, 0x43, 0x01, 0x03, 0x04,
    0x04, 0x05, 0x04, 0x05, 0x09, 0x05, 0x05, 0x09, 0x14, 0x0d, 0x0b, 0x0d, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14,
    0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14,
    0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14,
    0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0xff, 0xc2,
    0x00, 0x11, 0x08, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x20, 0x03, 0x01, 0x11, 0x00, 0x02, 0x11, 0x01, 0x03, 0x11,
    0x01, 0xff, 0xc4, 0x00, 0x19, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x07, 0x00, 0x03, 0x05, 0x04, 0xff, 0xc4, 0x00, 0x1b,
    0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x05, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x05, 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x06, 0x07, 0x01, 0xff, 0xda, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00,
    0x02, 0x10, 0x03, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x62, 0xd2, 0x78, 0x9f, 0x36, 0x29, 0x12, 0x2c, 0xe9,
    0x22, 0xc4, 0xf9, 0xb1, 0x4d, 0xd1, 0x33, 0x44, 0xb0, 0x8b, 0x43, 0xc5, 0x33, 0x4c, 0x00, 0x59,
    0xd0, 0x81, 0xca, 0xfd, 0x75, 0x26, 0x4e, 0xec, 0x7a, 0xaf, 0x13, 0x7e, 0x97, 0xf8, 0xda, 0xd9,
    0xd1, 0xff, 0xc4, 0x00, 0x1b, 0x10, 0x00, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x03, 0x01, 0x02, 0x07, 0x14, 0xff, 0xda,
    0x00, 0x08, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x05, 0x02, 0xad, 0xad, 0x3f, 0x16, 0xc2, 0x79, 0xe8, 0xe4,
    0x70, 0x5f, 0x9e, 0x8e, 0x3f, 0x12, 0x55, 0xa7, 0xec, 0xdb, 0xcf, 0x44, 0xfa, 0x03, 0x48, 0x90,
    0x84, 0x46, 0x3b, 0x48, 0x43, 0xd3, 0x3d, 0x08, 0x4f, 0x9c, 0x38, 0xa3, 0xb6, 0x0d, 0x3a, 0x97,
    0x80, 0xd3, 0x2c, 0x2d, 0xaa, 0xd9, 0xa5, 0xf4, 0xcd, 0x89, 0x6f, 0x3f, 0x5b, 0x24, 0x7e, 0xcd,
    0xb7, 0x76, 0x8c, 0xfe, 0xd9, 0xb5, 0x9f, 0x13, 0xbc, 0x94, 0x91, 0xf8, 0xb6, 0xff, 0xc4, 0x00,
    0x20, 0x11, 0x00, 0x02, 0x02, 0x01, 0x03, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x00, 0x03, 0x12, 0x04, 0x11, 0x21, 0x13, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x51, 0xff,
    0xda, 0x00, 0x08, 0x01, 0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x3f, 0x01, 0x44, 0x36, 0x1c, 0x56, 0x26, 0x91, 0x07,
    0x97, 0x31, 0xf4, 0x88, 0x7c, 0x78, 0x8e, 0x86, 0xb3, 0x8b, 0x4d, 0x22, 0x6c, 0x99, 0x7d, 0x88,
    0x86, 0xb2, 0xcc, 0xcd, 0x1d, 0x0d, 0x85, 0x59, 0x5a, 0x6a, 0xd3, 0x74, 0xcb, 0xe4, 0xd3, 0x3e,
    0xf5, 0xe2, 0x3b, 0x88, 0x8e, 0xb6, 0xae, 0xc6, 0x17, 0x4a, 0x84, 0xbe, 0xc3, 0xd2, 0xd8, 0xf7,
    0x31, 0x1c, 0xd6, 0x72, 0x59, 0xd6, 0xa6, 0xcf, 0x60, 0xe6, 0x1b, 0x69, 0xaf, 0xd6, 0x39, 0x8e,
    0xe6, 0xc3, 0x93, 0x4f, 0xff, 0xc4, 0x00, 0x2b, 0x11, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x03, 0x05, 0x08, 0x03,
    0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x00, 0x11, 0x21,
    0x05, 0x41, 0x61, 0x91, 0xb1, 0x06, 0x12, 0x22, 0x31, 0x51, 0x81, 0xa1, 0xc1, 0x14, 0x71, 0xf0,
    0x13, 0xff, 0xda, 0x00, 0x08, 0x01, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x3f, 0x01, 0x78, 0xf1, 0x26, 0x29, 0x0a,
    0xcb, 0x0d, 0x35, 0xc0, 0x21, 0xe6, 0xd4, 0x3a, 0x54, 0xc2, 0x0d, 0xb8, 0x0b, 0x77, 0x5e, 0xf7,
    0x7e, 0xe7, 0x0c, 0xf6, 0xa1, 0xd2, 0x46, 0x00, 0x73, 0xc6, 0x5b, 0xfa, 0xf6, 0xbb, 0xf7, 0x38,
    0x66, 0xf1, 0x27, 0xc9, 0x02, 0xc8, 0x8d, 0x34, 0xc0, 0x63, 0x6a, 0x1e, 0x19, 0x57, 0x5f, 0x18,
    0x07, 0x84, 0x97, 0x63, 0xd7, 0x2f, 0x70, 0xf5, 0xea, 0x4f, 0x92, 0x45, 0x04, 0x11, 0xdd, 0x31,
    0x69, 0x4d, 0x03, 0x5a, 0xcc, 0x66, 0x3f, 0x62, 0x2c, 0x9e, 0xa4, 0xc5, 0x25, 0x90, 0x5d, 0x1d,
    0xe3, 0x1a, 0x95, 0xd0, 0x75, 0xa4, 0x86, 0x61, 0xf4, 0x21, 0xb2, 0xef, 0x0c, 0x93, 0xaf, 0x8c,
    0x23, 0xc2, 0x7b, 0xb1, 0xeb, 0x97, 0xa8, 0xda, 0x16, 0x40, 0x47, 0xe5, 0x5d, 0x49, 0xff, 0x00,
    0x33, 0xca, 0x63, 0xe3, 0x4a, 0xe7, 0x0e, 0x99, 0x38, 0xb3, 0x57, 0xdf, 0x20, 0x50, 0x06, 0x65,
    0x37, 0x30, 0xc3, 0x08, 0x49, 0xab, 0xab, 0x45, 0x61, 0x12, 0x96, 0x62, 0x61, 0xa8, 0xdd, 0x16,
    0x2d, 0x9c, 0x42, 0xda, 0x47, 0x51, 0x11, 0x11, 0x4d, 0x3b, 0xfa, 0x9a, 0x52, 0xf6, 0x3e, 0x21,
    0xe3, 0x34, 0x9f, 0x24, 0x28, 0xac, 0x14, 0xd3, 0x10, 0x83, 0x59, 0x56, 0xb5, 0x9e, 0x22, 0x0c,
    0x14, 0x99, 0x2e, 0x09, 0xd7, 0xcd, 0x32, 0xca, 0x13, 0xb3, 0x6d, 0x87, 0xd4, 0x7c, 0xae, 0xe9,
    0x2f, 0x09, 0xd6, 0x5d, 0xa9, 0x9e, 0x50, 0xcd, 0x9a, 0x4c, 0x52, 0x04, 0x51, 0x0a, 0x6b, 0x88,
    0xc7, 0xff, 0xc4, 0x00, 0x29, 0x10, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x05, 0x02, 0x05, 0x04, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x05, 0x11, 0x12, 0x21, 0x00, 0x41,
    0x13, 0x22, 0x51, 0x61, 0x91, 0x31, 0x32, 0x71, 0xa1, 0x06, 0x14, 0x81, 0xff, 0xda, 0x00, 0x08,
    0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x06, 0x3f, 0x02, 0x14, 0x8e, 0x46, 0x21, 0x96, 0x62, 0x46, 0x5e, 0x53, 0x93,
    0x2d, 0x87, 0x6f, 0x5f, 0x9d, 0xf3, 0xdb, 0x0b, 0x5d, 0x0c, 0xd3, 0xb8, 0xa8, 0x99, 0xbc, 0x67,
    0x0e, 0xc7, 0x71, 0x4c, 0xeb, 0x53, 0x35, 0xe5, 0xdf, 0xef, 0xf9, 0xa2, 0x9a, 0x49, 0x15, 0x13,
    0x28, 0x8c, 0xe1, 0xd8, 0xde, 0x11, 0x9d, 0x6a, 0xe6, 0xbc, 0xdb, 0xfd, 0xff, 0x00, 0x34, 0x59,
    0x1c, 0xf0, 0x43, 0x14, 0xc4, 0x6c, 0xbc, 0x47, 0x1e, 0x1b, 0x10, 0xde, 0xbf, 0x3b, 0xe3, 0xbe,
    0x12, 0x9a, 0x8a, 0x9d, 0x98, 0x62, 0xfd, 0xc9, 0x89, 0xc8, 0x4b, 0x99, 0x5c, 0x36, 0xef, 0x6f,
    0x6e, 0x6a, 0xfd, 0x6a, 0x6b, 0x19, 0x19, 0x35, 0x7c, 0x40, 0x0c, 0xee, 0x25, 0x0b, 0x44, 0x46,
    0xa5, 0x3d, 0xce, 0xe8, 0xbb, 0x62, 0x89, 0x44, 0xf1, 0x2a, 0x8c, 0x83, 0x9a, 0xbe, 0x1c, 0x01,
    0x77, 0x12, 0x82, 0xa2, 0xa3, 0x92, 0x9e, 0xe6, 0xf5, 0x5d, 0xb3, 0x54, 0xa2, 0xf9, 0x85, 0x9d,
    0x84, 0x62, 0xfd, 0xc9, 0x71, 0xc6, 0x4b, 0x9f, 0x5c, 0xb6, 0xef, 0x6f, 0x7e, 0x6a, 0x7d, 0xea,
    0x63, 0x26, 0x6b, 0x80, 0x49, 0xa4, 0xb0, 0x85, 0x63, 0x04, 0x95, 0xa3, 0xf3, 0xeb, 0xdd, 0x2e,
    0xaa, 0x78, 0xd2, 0x84, 0xce, 0x63, 0x4c, 0x46, 0x28, 0xe2, 0x21, 0x55, 0x6d, 0x73, 0x57, 0xd1,
    0xc9, 0x4f, 0x5d, 0x35, 0xa4, 0x33, 0x02, 0x20, 0xb1, 0x18, 0x31, 0x5d, 0x57, 0x2a, 0x27, 0xa2,
    0x26, 0xeb, 0xa9, 0x6c, 0xb0, 0xa8, 0x18, 0x69, 0x9c, 0xd4, 0xcc, 0x6f, 0x01, 0xd5, 0xe4, 0x65,
    0xd8, 0x55, 0xe9, 0x9b, 0x7e, 0xf4, 0x29, 0xe4, 0x8c, 0xa3, 0x14, 0xc4, 0x6c, 0xb0, 0xa0, 0x26,
    0x1b, 0x10, 0xde, 0x9f, 0x3b, 0x67, 0xb6, 0x52, 0x9a, 0x1b, 0x3f, 0x26, 0x93, 0x92, 0x5d, 0x30,
    0x51, 0xdc, 0xe7, 0x14, 0x0e, 0x6d, 0xdb, 0x62, 0x9c, 0xda, 0x7b, 0x7f, 0x1b, 0x92, 0x92, 0x69,
    0x30, 0x6b, 0x2f, 0x63, 0x98, 0x07, 0xbd, 0x19, 0x9a, 0x55, 0x6b, 0xcd, 0xe3, 0xce, 0x8b, 0x3c,
    0x9e, 0x14, 0x65, 0x98, 0x91, 0x96, 0x08, 0x03, 0xcb, 0x61, 0xdb, 0xd3, 0xe7, 0x6c, 0x77, 0xca,
    0xd7, 0x5f, 0xff, 0xc4, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x10, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x11, 0x21, 0x31, 0x00, 0x51, 0x41, 0x61, 0xc1,
    0xff, 0xda, 0x00, 0x08, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x3f, 0x21, 0xcd, 0xb0, 0x11, 0xc1, 0x04, 0x0e,
    0x0c, 0xca, 0x47, 0x96, 0x02, 0xb4, 0x50, 0xef, 0x8c, 0x59, 0x25, 0x4d, 0x86, 0xac, 0x5c, 0x54,
    0xa2, 0x83, 0x7c, 0x62, 0xd9, 0x60, 0x64, 0x10, 0x6a, 0x6e, 0x6d, 0x80, 0x86, 0x00, 0x81, 0x75,
    0x6e, 0x52, 0x1d, 0xb1, 0x22, 0xb2, 0x5e, 0xef, 0x42, 0xf1, 0x0e, 0x0b, 0x4d, 0x2c, 0xc8, 0x10,
    0xf9, 0x02, 0x0a, 0x9c, 0x00, 0xf4, 0x0e, 0x70, 0xf3, 0x42, 0x1f, 0x22, 0x45, 0x13, 0x88, 0x3e,
    0xc1, 0xce, 0x9e, 0x49, 0xac, 0x17, 0x9b, 0xc2, 0x9c, 0x53, 0x8a, 0x43, 0x09, 0x75, 0x04, 0x82,
    0xd0, 0x0a, 0x6a, 0x51, 0xd0, 0x90, 0xd0, 0x5d, 0x47, 0xa5, 0x7d, 0xc3, 0xa5, 0x8e, 0xef, 0xef,
    0x87, 0x36, 0x63, 0x38, 0x82, 0xb4, 0xc3, 0xf7, 0xc6, 0x27, 0xef, 0xb7, 0xf7, 0xce, 0x1d, 0x9f,
    0x53, 0x19, 0x9b, 0x60, 0x21, 0x82, 0x89, 0x0d, 0x59, 0xb4, 0x87, 0x2d, 0x4f, 0xd6, 0x4e, 0x7b,
    0x8b, 0xd4, 0x63, 0x29, 0x08, 0x95, 0x9b, 0x63, 0x81, 0xd3, 0x7d, 0x05, 0x28, 0xe3, 0x68, 0x45,
    0xcc, 0xdb, 0x01, 0x1c, 0x05, 0x0a, 0x60, 0xdd, 0xa4, 0x7b, 0x69, 0xff, 0xda, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x03,
    0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x36, 0x9b, 0xb5, 0x7a, 0x13, 0x09, 0xff,
    0xc4, 0x00, 0x1f, 0x11, 0x00, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x21, 0x00, 0x11, 0xa1, 0xb1, 0x41, 0xf1, 0x61, 0xd1, 0xf0, 0x51,
    0xff, 0xda, 0x00, 0x08, 0x01, 0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x3f, 0x10, 0x05, 0x03, 0x80, 0x41, 0x76, 0x3d,
    0xc0, 0x24, 0xbb, 0x1e, 0xe1, 0x28, 0x1c, 0x05, 0xd0, 0xf4, 0xee, 0x5f, 0x40, 0x16, 0xf6, 0x74,
    0x95, 0x62, 0xba, 0x00, 0x35, 0xb1, 0xa6, 0xab, 0x20, 0xaa, 0x1e, 0x9d, 0xc2, 0x92, 0x86, 0x50,
    0xfb, 0xcc, 0xe5, 0x01, 0x44, 0x6e, 0x54, 0x49, 0xa0, 0x38, 0x85, 0x00, 0x6b, 0x83, 0xc7, 0xd5,
    0x98, 0x0a, 0x47, 0x00, 0x21, 0x1f, 0xae, 0x9c, 0x65, 0x6f, 0x03, 0xc6, 0x5c, 0x25, 0x23, 0x9f,
    0xff, 0xc4, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x11, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x11, 0x21, 0x31, 0x41, 0xa1, 0x00, 0x61, 0x91, 0xff, 0xda,
    0x00, 0x08, 0x01, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x3f, 0x10, 0x82, 0xb0, 0xc3, 0xab, 0x81, 0xd5, 0xf2, 0xd5,
    0x01, 0x40, 0xa0, 0x92, 0xd0, 0x2c, 0xcd, 0x4d, 0xb6, 0x02, 0xa8, 0x95, 0xa8, 0x50, 0x49, 0x68,
    0x02, 0x66, 0x22, 0x9b, 0x09, 0x76, 0x42, 0x92, 0x4a, 0xcb, 0x4e, 0xae, 0x87, 0x13, 0xda, 0x45,
    0x11, 0x42, 0xa2, 0x02, 0x78, 0x59, 0x38, 0xdb, 0x01, 0x39, 0x82, 0xd5, 0x01, 0x20, 0xe8, 0xaa,
    0xb4, 0x1a, 0x8b, 0xfa, 0x00, 0x3f, 0x10, 0x12, 0x0e, 0x82, 0x23, 0x61, 0xa0, 0x3f, 0x80, 0x0b,
    0xf1, 0x4a, 0x88, 0x18, 0xe0, 0x24, 0xeb, 0x28, 0x8c, 0x6e, 0x8a, 0x10, 0xa6, 0x10, 0xce, 0x29,
    0x2c, 0x15, 0x55, 0x00, 0xeb, 0x49, 0x84, 0x0d, 0xb9, 0x20, 0x09, 0x01, 0x95, 0x30, 0xcb, 0x24,
    0x7f, 0x91, 0xf3, 0xe6, 0x71, 0x82, 0x02, 0xb2, 0xab, 0x00, 0x1d, 0xf0, 0x39, 0xf1, 0x54, 0x44,
    0x2b, 0x08, 0x11, 0xfa, 0x02, 0x56, 0x42, 0x58, 0x49, 0x92, 0xb2, 0xc7, 0xab, 0x89, 0xc4, 0xf6,
    0xc4, 0x45, 0x1b, 0xb1, 0xd6, 0x08, 0x0d, 0xca, 0x1c, 0xb4, 0xaa, 0x5a, 0x61, 0x60, 0x88, 0xd9,
    0x20, 0x04, 0xa1, 0xc0, 0xef, 0x2d, 0x56, 0xca, 0x01, 0x82, 0xb0, 0xd7, 0xab, 0xa9, 0xd5, 0xf2,
    0x80, 0x00, 0x0f, 0xff, 0xc4, 0x00, 0x1b, 0x10, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x11, 0x00, 0x21, 0x41, 0x31, 0x61, 0x51,
    0xff, 0xda, 0x00, 0x08, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x3f, 0x10, 0x45, 0x2d, 0x61, 0x3c, 0x59, 0xdd,
    0xda, 0x00, 0x13, 0x41, 0x8e, 0xaa, 0xf7, 0xa1, 0x47, 0x15, 0x7a, 0x1c, 0x06, 0x38, 0x6a, 0xaf,
    0x78, 0x54, 0x75, 0x57, 0xa1, 0xc4, 0x60, 0x29, 0x6b, 0x01, 0xe2, 0xce, 0x6e, 0x52, 0x02, 0x9a,
    0x0e, 0x3f, 0xa7, 0x4c, 0x40, 0xdf, 0xd1, 0x80, 0x80, 0x62, 0x60, 0x6b, 0xa5, 0xc5, 0x83, 0xc1,
    0xb5, 0xac, 0x6e, 0x18, 0x1a, 0xe9, 0x70, 0x61, 0xf4, 0x6d, 0x69, 0x1b, 0x9c, 0x7f, 0x4e, 0x88,
    0x81, 0x9f, 0xa3, 0x01, 0x08, 0xc2, 0x65, 0xdc, 0x2a, 0xea, 0xd2, 0x02, 0x12, 0x58, 0x0e, 0x29,
    0x38, 0xb6, 0x1e, 0xe0, 0x29, 0x48, 0x1b, 0x3d, 0x03, 0x23, 0xfc, 0x80, 0x06, 0xed, 0x40, 0x15,
    0xbf, 0xd5, 0xf5, 0xcf, 0x16, 0xb7, 0xaf, 0x97, 0xba, 0x44, 0xd1, 0x44, 0x2b, 0xa2, 0x29, 0x69,
    0x01, 0xe2, 0xce, 0x6e, 0x52, 0x40, 0x9a, 0x25, 0x1b, 0x87, 0xf3, 0x45, 0x94, 0xdf, 0x59, 0xe0,
    0xe7, 0x04, 0x1d, 0x40, 0x4a, 0xa4, 0x1a, 0x91, 0x3a, 0xe2, 0x70, 0x14, 0xb4, 0x84, 0xf1, 0x67,
    0x77, 0x68, 0x21, 0x4d, 0x1f, 0xff, 0xd9
];

let imageURI = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64encode(data);
let img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = imageURI;
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: in base64encode im using as b64encoded= btoa(data) is this correct

Comment: by using above function i got the result as data:image/jpeg;base64,++++++WebKitFormBoundary1E6VkKBHSGzUMTIgContent+Dispositionform+dataname

Comment: before using my function my data is  [251, 239, 190, 251, 229, 158, 108, 168, 173, 22, 138, 230, 6, 139, 167, 117, 170, 242, 145, 168, 137, 66, 117, 186, 201, 190, 214, 230, 133, 31, 10, 137, 237, 122, 123, 126, 14, 43, 41, 162, 200, 173, 138, 137, 223, 162, 185, 190, 117, 171, 90, 157, 169, 158]

Comment: @venkatesh - *"in base64encode im using as b64encoded= btoa(data) is this correct"* No. There's a full example in the answer, and as you can see, more is required. Re your other two comments: Clearly `data` **doesn't** contain just image data, it looks like one part of a multipart form body. You'll need to parse that body via an appropriate body parser (it's non-trivial, you'll want to find a library for it).

Comment: i have used this function base64encode(data) {
    return btoa(data.map(v => String.fromCharCode(v)).join(""));
} and result is data:image/jpeg;base64,++++++WebKitFormBoundarykaiJQnW6yb7W5oUfContent+Dispositionform+dataname

Comment: @venkatesh - Again: *"Re your other two comments: Clearly data doesn't contain just image data, it looks like one part of a multipart form body. You'll need to parse that body via an appropriate body parser (it's non-trivial, you'll want to find a library for it)."*

Comment: another one
------WebKitFormBoundaryTLywNaHWnuaGfU4m
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profileImage"

data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxISEhUTEhIWFRUVFRYWFhUWFxUXFxUVFRUWFhUVFRcYHSggGBolHRUXITEhJSktLi------4qi2y7hrMXhimET2jEBLQCnLAHSANFB0Hvr07gQ/w1j/ACLX+mtKlQxVU/C/2Phu4+Q6KUUqVTHFSpUqwThqJ6VKgEGuGlSpVjH/2Q==
------WebKitFormBoundaryTLywNaHWnuaGfU4m
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"

building.jpeg
------WebKitFormBoundaryTLywNaHWnuaGfU4m--

how to take only data:image-------, skipping webkitFormboundary at starting and ending of that data

Comment: @venkatesh - ***Again***: *"Re your other two comments: Clearly data doesn't contain just image data, **it looks like one part of a multipart form body.** You'll need to parse that body via an appropriate body parser (it's non-trivial, you'll want to find a library for it)."*